# Hurwitz's matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, sums-of-squares

I have a question about the proof of Hurwitz's 1-2-4-8 theorem about the sum of squares.

I have consulted Chapter 1 of Rajwade's "Squares" book, [notes by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/hurwitzlinear.pdf), and [notes by Daniel Shapiro](http://math.osu.edu/~shapiro.6/lec1.pdf). They all feature the same step that I am confused about.

Namely, they derive identity
$$
  (Y_1,Y_2,\dotsc,Y_n)[(X_1^2+X_2^2+\dotsc+X_n^2)I_n-A^TA]\begin{pmatrix}Y_1\\Y_2\\\vdots\\Y_n\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
where $Y_1,\dotsc,Y_n,X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are indeterminates, and $A$ is a matrix whose entries are linear forms in $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$. From that they somehow deduce that 
$$
A^T A=(X_1^2+X_2^2+\dotsc+X_n^2)I_n.
$$

```
Question 1:Is this a correct deduction? If so, why?
```

As far as I can tell, we can derive only a weaker conclusion. Namely, writing $A=X_1A_1+X_2A_2+\dotsb+X_nA_n$, and expanding everything as a sum of monomials in $X_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_n$ we obtain that
$$
(Y_1,Y_2,\dotsc,Y_n)(A_i^TA_i-I_n)\begin{pmatrix}Y_1\\Y_2\\\vdots\\Y_n\end{pmatrix}=0\qquad\text{for each }i=1,\dotsc,n.
$$
and there certainly exist non-zero matrices $M$ such that $Y^TMY=0$. For example,
$$
(Y_1,Y_2)\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}Y_1\\Y_2\end{pmatrix}=0.
$$

I thought that I could rescue this by showing that $A_i^T A_i$ is same for all $i$ (and then one can just change coordinates, and run the proof of Hurwitz's theorem unchanged), but my fix was wrong (as called out by a student in my class today).

```
Question 2: If this step is indeed in error, how does a correct proof go?
```

Sadly, I do not have training in German, and my attempt to use a dictionary to understand how Hurwitz made this step in [his original paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/loader/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002498200) was unsuccessful. I can read English, Russian and French. I would thus welcome references in those languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Conrad's notes he writes "as $\bf y$ varies" just before (2.4)

If you have a symmetric matrix $M$ and column vectors $y$ such that $y^T M y = 0$ for every $y,$ this means that $M=0.$ This assumes that the characteristic of the field is not $2.$

First, we get the resulting bilinear form from
$$ x^T M y = (1/2) \left( (x+y)^T M (x+y) - x^T M x - y^T M y  \right). $$
The right hand side is always $0,$ so $x^T My$ is always $0.$

Now take $x$ as the vector with entry $i$ set to $1,$ all other entries $0.$ Take $y$ as the vector with entry $j$ set to $1,$ all other entries $0.$ Then $x^T M y = M_{ij}.$ Therefore $M_{ij}=0.$ We do this for each $ij$ ordered pair, with the result that $M=0.$

Comment: Ah, I am a dope! Matrix $A_i^T A_i$ is not arbitrary, it is symmetric! (By the way, you should edit your answer to require $M$ being symmetric, as it is false otherwise.)